# React - Each child in array .. unique "key" prop warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I appear to have a decent understanding of this principal, which allows me to get by, until now. I am applying a key prop to all children of all iterators, and yet I'm still getting this warning.

A `FacilitiesContainer` is rendering a `FacilitiesComponent`, which in turn renders a list of `Facilities`, which renders a list of `Courses`. A `Course` does not use an iterator. However, the `FacilitiesContainer` is passing the `FacilitiesComponent` through a HOC, which is returning the final component. There's nothing in the HOC that modifies the passed components, so I'm not sure if this is a problem.

```
// The render method of FacilitiesContainer 
render = () => {
    let FacilitiesWithSearch = SearchHOC(
      BasicSearch, 
      FacilitiesComponent, 
      {data: this.state.facilities }
    );
    return <FacilitiesWithSearch />;
  }


class FacilitiesComponent extends Component {
  renderFacilities = () => (
    this.props.data.map((facilityData, index) =>
      <Facility key={index} data={facilityData} />
    )
  )

  render = () => (
    <Grid>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} sm={8} smOffset={2} md={8} mdOffset={1}>
          {
            this.props.data.length > 0
              ? this.renderFacilities()
              : <div>No results</div>
          }
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  )
}

const Facility = ({ data }) => (
  <Panel>
    <Panel.Heading>
      <Panel.Title>{data.Name}</Panel.Title>
    </Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Body>
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <p><b>Address:</b><br />
            {data.Street}<br />
            {data.City}, {data.State} {data.Zip}
          </p>
          <p><b>Phone:</b> {data.Phone}</p>
            {
              data.Courses.map((courseData, index) =>
                <p><Course key={index} data={courseData} /></p>)
            }
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    </Panel.Body>
  </Panel>
);
```

Comment: Using index as key is not recommended action. You can read docs about keys from official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Cheers. Looks like I messed up in multiple areas here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You indeed didn't provide keys to `p` elements here:

```
{
  data.Courses.map((courseData, index) =>
    <p><Course key={index} data={courseData} /></p>)
}
```

Should be

```
{
  data.Courses.map((courseData, index) =>
    <p key={index}><Course data={courseData} /></p>)
}
```

Comment: Excellent eye. Cheers. I actually did not think about the <p> elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try to append a string to the index before assigning it to the key. That's because you are only using index (0,1,2...) both for your list of facilities and list of courses, so there will be duplicated indexes in the final rendered component. If you do as below you ensure that each index is unique:

```
<Facility key={`facility_${index}`} data={facilityData} />
```

and

```
<Course key={`course_${index}`} data={courseData} />
```

Comment: Cheers. Looks like this is the preferred way according to the docs. Combined with the missing keys, everything works!